# TrueCrypt with blank password

Tags: truecrypt

This might sound like an odd question, but please hear me out. I want to setup my laptop to use TrueCrypt, but without a password.  My wife doesn't travel much with her notebook. There are occasions where we will have to travel and bring the notebook with us. This is when we would like the have the encryption.

The time it takes to to change the unlock pass-phrase is considerably less than it takes to encrypt the drive. My thoughts are to leave the disk encrypted but with no password. Then when it's time to pack for a trip and bring the laptop, we would then change the pass-phrase and create a rescue disk.

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: Usually, the only time you need to enter a TrueCrypt password (depending of course on how you've set it up) is at boot time. Why not just leave it password-protected? It's a good habit to have.

Comment: I tried, but it won't let me continue to change the password if the `NEW` Password fields are blank.

Comment: Make it a very simple password, like `go` or `start`.

Comment: @TheSavo: Since TrueCrypt is open source, you should be able to modify the source code and recompile the program to make it accept blank passwords. :)